# php foreach() w/ MySQL WHERE w/ while{} returning only the last array() item

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop

My result is spitting out a duplicate of each record as opposed to a unique foreach match. As you can see I am trying to loop through and get each unique value **WHERE $s=id**.. I know the query needs to be within the **while()**,

The array $seminar being passed from checkboxes on my form.

```
if ($seminar) {
    foreach ($seminar as $s)
        $interest .= "$s ";
}
```

NOTE: The **$interest** is what I am using to insert into my table (it's not part of this problem)

For array data, this is what is being returned by **$seminar**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 10
    [4] => 13
)
```

Here is my code:

```
$query_seminars = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(moment) FROM seminars WHERE id={$s}");
    while ($sem_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_seminars))
    {
        $names .= "-- " . $sem_row['id'] . " " . $sem_row['name'] . date('D, F j, Y, g:i a',     $sem_row['moment']) . "<br />";

}
```

Comment: You mix up the variables $sem_row and $seminar - your PHP should throw a lot of warnings if you set the appropriate error reporting. Just kick the foreach and you will be happy.

Comment: BurninLeo, its still not working. I can produce the array. I updated my above code to show exactly what I am working with now.. I can only get the last item of the array() (in the above case 13) record to print out.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need the foreach in the while loop, here:

```
$query_seminars = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(moment) FROM seminars WHERE id={$s}");
while ($sem_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_seminars))
{
    $names .= "-- " . $sem_row['id'] . " " . $sem_row['name'] . date('D, F j, Y,     g:i a', $sem_row['moment']) . "<br />";
}
```

Also to use named indexes you use `mysql_fetch_assoc`, not `mysql_fetch_array`. (Already in above code)

Comment: This is the exact problem I am running into. I was able to produce this result earlier. I am only getting that last item on the $s array, so only one record is printing out. I am updating my code above to show how my array is being generated.

Comment: I meant $seminar array not $s array.

Comment: @OldWest that's because you have `WHERE id={$s}`. That's limiting your result set to 1 record, remove that bit of code and all records will appear.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that MySql is returning duplicate (actualy tri-plicate) items. The problem is that you are iterating over each record with your `foreach`, as others pointed out.

One usual idiom used with MySql is:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(moment) FROM seminars WHERE $s=id";

if ($q = mysql_query($sql)) {
  while ($f = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    //($f is an associative array of the record value, 
    //with keys for each field)
    //... do something with $f
    echo "--" . htmlspecialchars($f['name']) 
      . date('D, F j, Y, g:i a', $f['moment']) 
      . "<br /><br />";
  }
} elseif ($e = mysql_error()) {
//do something with the error message
//...
}
```

You are seeing "duplicates" because you are using a `foreach` inside the while loop to iterate by each **field** of the returned record. Since your query is returning records with three fields each (*id*, *name* and *moment*), you are processing each record three times.

Comment: Hi Branco, thanks for the comments, but this is still not working. I can only get the last item of my array() to print with my foreach. I updated my above code to show what I am doing now.